# How to get AWS Kinesis Firehose stream details using the Java SDK

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Is it possible to get details like buffer size and buffer interval from an AWS Firehose stream using the Java SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DescribeDeliveryStream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeDeliveryStream.html) to get details like Buffer Size and interval for the Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream.

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kinesisfirehose/AmazonKinesisFirehose.html#describeDeliveryStream-com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.model.DescribeDeliveryStreamRequest-) is the relevant Java reference

Comment: This is what I've done:                                  
    'DescribeDeliveryStreamRequest describeHoseRequest = new 
    DescribeDeliveryStreamRequest()
                .withDeliveryStreamName(Properties.getUasFirehoseDeliveryStreamName());

    DescribeDeliveryStreamResult describeHoseResult = firehoseClient.describeDeliveryStream(describeHoseRequest);

    String json = describeHoseResult.getDeliveryStreamDescription().toString();'